# NoClassDefFoundError after converting simple java project to maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I have a class that I coded in a standard java project in eclipse on OSX (Java 1.6).  The class uses classes and interfaces from another library.
I select the class, then do Run As > Java Application and all works well.

After that I try to run my project as a Maven project and things start to get a little frustrating..  I summarise all the steps here hoping that someone will tell me what I am doing wrong:
- From the standard java project I right click and did Configure > Convert to Maven project and clicked Finnish.  All good so far.

- Then Build Path > Configure Build Path > and add the folder that contains my project. Still good
- THEN I remove all the @Override annotations since I read somewhere on SO that Maven uses JDK 1.5 instead of 1.6.  Whatever, I remove them and my red flags go away.  At this point my class looks exactly like in the original java project (except for the @override that I removed)
- THEN I do Maven > clean.  I get build success
- THEN Maven > Install. I get a build success
- THEN I select my class and do Run As > Java Application and I get this ugly looking trace:

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LMAXTrading/algos/HeartbeatClient
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LMAXTrading.algos.HeartbeatClient
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

I don't know where to go from here.  You can imagine that I went through a lot of trials and errors and searched on SO and elsewhere to find a way to get this to work.  But I just cannot figure out what is wrong. So if someone has an idea I am so ready to listen.

I am pasting below my directory layout from the Navigator View as well as from the Package explorer view

[image: layout Navigator view]

[image]

And here is the POM.xml where I have added the JRE config

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>someproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>someproject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Maven can use any version of Java. You're misinformed on this - just configure the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: Did you added the necesary Maven dependencies in pom.xml?

Comment: Given how much has changed, it might be worth doing a Project > Clean from the Eclipse menus.

Comment: @MateiFlorescu as I said my project works fine before converting to Maven

Comment: Try right-click on the project -> Maven -> Update Project. Also check your run configuration, there is a tab called "Classpath" and there you must have an entry called "Maven Dependencies".

Comment: @mattb I did: Configure build path > Java Compiler > Compliance level 1.6 and also changed the librarie to Java SE 6.  The Maven > Clean and Maven > Install.  I get build success for both BUT in the stack trace there is this message "No sources to compile".  Any idea why?

Comment: You need to configure Maven, not your IDE. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html and set source and target to 1.6

Comment: @mattb I still get [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ someproject ---
[INFO] No sources to compile.  How do I make it to look into the right  folder.

Comment: What does your directory layout look like? Where is your source code?

Comment: @mattb I have added my directory tree

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The project directory structure does not match with the default Maven directory structure. Maven expects the source to be in `src/main/java` directory under the root folder (the folder containing `pom.xml`). The source here is in the `src` folder hence the `No sources to compile` error.

You can either move your sources to use the default Maven directory structure or change the `pom.xml` to explicitly specify your source directory by adding the following to the `build` section of the pom:

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
```

More info on Maven's standard directory layouts can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: I have added <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> to POM and the build progresses to this point: "[ERROR] mypath/someproject/src/LMAXTrading/algos/HeartbeatClient.java:[3,19] package com.lmax.api does not exist."  which is a package in the jar that is in MYLYBRARIES library (as per my screenshot above). Is there another source I am supposed to add to POM for that library to automatically get picked?

Comment: @jule64 you need to add those libraries as dependencies in your Maven POM. Read up the Maven docs on how to do that.

Comment: thanks! it works now.  Wow that was painful.  The Configure > Convert to Maven Project option really works about as well as a as a broken coffee machine.  Thanks all for your helpful advices.

Comment: @jule64 How about clicking that little green tick then?